# How to start appium two times one by one with different port using java?

Tags: java, appium

I want to run multiple instances of the appium using different port using java programming.

E.g pseudo

```
for( 2 times){  
int port = getRendomFreePort()
StartAppiumUsingPort(port)
driver = CreateAppiumDriver() 
PerformTest()
CloseAppiumDriver()
CloseAppium()
}
```

While doing the above steps using the actual code, I am getting an error for appium driver after the appium start.

I have written code as following:

1st sample: Just open two times with same port and successfully run java program

```
for( 2 times){
int port = getSamePort() // Using Same port
StartAppiumUsingPort(port)

// node creating appium driver
CloseAppiumDriver()
CloseAppium()
}
```

2st sample: open two times and creating an appium driver with the same port and getting an error on driver creation

```
for( 2 times){
int port = getSamePort() // Using Same port
StartAppiumUsingPort(port)
driver = CreateAppiumDriver() 
PerformTest()
CloseAppiumDriver()
CloseAppium()
}
```

**APK.java**

```
public class APK {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = null;
        DesiredCapabilities caps = null;
        APK apk = new APK();
        AppiumServerJava appiumServer = new AppiumServerJava();

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

            System.out.println("======== " + i + " ==============");
            String appiumURl = null;
            int port = 4723;
            if (!appiumServer.checkIfServerIsRunnning(port)) {
                appiumURl = appiumServer.startServer(port);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Appium Server already running on Port - " + port);
            }

            // Storing required values
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("platform_", "ANDROID"); // IOS || ANDROID

            if (params.get("platform_").equals("ANDROID")) {

                params.put("deviceName_", "emulator-5554");
                params.put("UDID_", "emulator-5554");
                params.put("platformVersion_", "7.0.0");
                params.put("URL_", appiumURl);

                params.put("appUrl_",
                        "apkPath");

            }

            caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
            apk.initCaps(params, caps);


            driver = new AppiumDriver<MobileElement>(new URL(params.get("URL_")), caps);

            if (!appiumServer.checkIfServerIsRunnning(port)) {
                appiumServer.stopServer();
                System.out.println("stopped");
            }
        }
    }

    private void initCaps(Map<String, String> params, DesiredCapabilities caps) {
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, params.get("deviceName_"));
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, params.get("platform_").split("_")[0]);
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, params.get("platformVersion_"));
        caps.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 1500);
        if (params.get("platform_").equalsIgnoreCase("ANDROID")) {
            File app = new File(params.get("appUrl_"));
            caps.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
            caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, false); //false
        } 
        caps.setCapability("udid", params.get("UDID_"));
        caps.setCapability("appActivity", "pack.android.MainActivity");
        caps.setCapability("automationName", "uiautomator2");
        caps.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", "true");
    }

}
```

**AppiumServer.java**

```
public String startServer(int port) throws Exception {
        //Set Capabilities
        cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability("noReset", "false");

        //Build the Appium service
        builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
        builder.withIPAddress("127.0.0.1");
        builder.usingPort(port);
        builder.withCapabilities(cap);
        builder.withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.SESSION_OVERRIDE);
        builder.withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.LOG_LEVEL,"debug");

        //Start the server with the builder
        service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(builder);
        service.start();
        System.out.println("URL:" + service.getUrl().toString());
        return service.getUrl().toString();
    }

public void stopServer() {
        if(service.isRunning()) {
            System.out.println("Server is getting closed : " + service.getUrl());
            service.stop();
            System.out.println("Server is  closed.");
        }

    }
```

Error Log:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'CF-LP00152.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:4f6:6753:cd93:37c7%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: driver.version: AppiumDriver
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:195)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:209)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:231)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:212)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:84)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:94)
    at sample.code.help.APK.main(APK.java:68)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:185)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find adb Please set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable with the Android SDK root directory path.
Driver info: driver.version: AppiumDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find adb Please set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable with the Android SDK root directory path.
    at getResponseForW3CError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:826:9)
    at asyncHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:447:37)
    at <anonymous>
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$new$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:122)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:125)
    ... 16 more
```

Comment: Unrelated: I would suggest to **never** use *random* port numbers. Decide on the first one to use, and then simply go +1 from there. Typically, port numbers are something that **two** sides are interested in, and randomizing isnt exactly helping. (and if you think a random port number helps with security ... well, no, not really)

Comment: you need to start two appium server in two different port. The you need to intialize two different AppiumDriver. You must specify port number while initializing DesiredCapability. If you need further help, let me know.

Comment: @SubanDhyako I am creating driver one by one. So once 1st run is finished then I am closing it. and again reinitializing driver

Comment: Please set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable with the Android SDK root directory path

Comment: ANDROID_HOME is set in .bash_profile and also in eclipse run configuration environmet. What I am observing is driver.close() and driver.quit(). if I use driver.close() then object session will be there and hence failing. and if I use driver.quit() then i will work as it will create new session after quit() method.